# Snugshade size limiting

Tags: tables

Im trying to limit the area that is turned black with my code to just the one line i have text in insted of the now three[image]. But latex is hard i guess.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{comment} % enables the use of multi-line comments (\ifx \fi) 
\usepackage{fullpage} % changes the margin
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{multicol}
%\usepackage[head=128pt]{geometry}
\title{\textsc{Extra Curricular Achievements}}
\author{Erik Jonasson}
\usepackage{geometry}
\setlength{\footskip}{0.1pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{80pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\begin{document}

\newcommand\FUM{5} 


\begin{snugshade*}
    \noindent\textsc{\section*{\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \color{white}{F18-{\FUM}.1} 
    & \color{white}{Formalia} 
\end{tabular}}}
\end{snugshade*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Does [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82029/121799) help? And a general remark: please do not assume that everyone knows what `snugshade` is. Therefore always provide use with a minimal working example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`, and can be compiled and illustrates the issue. You will see that when doing this you will get much more valuable feedback.

Comment: Your code is still not compilable as at lest the following code is missing in the preamble: `\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0,0,0}`. Additionally, `\FUM` is undefined.

Comment: The MWE does not compile

Comment: Are you trying to get a background color for your headings? If so, this is quite easy with a KOMA-script document class, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269013/4736 .

Comment: yeah nice thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case you don't want to use KOMA classes, you can try some variants with `snugshade`. First the original, then without the noindent and smallcaps (which did not work anyway), then with the `snugshade` within the `section`, and finally with the `snugshade` in the `section` and without the `tabular`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{framed}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\begin{document}

\begin{snugshade}
    \noindent\textsc{\section*{\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \color{white}{F18-5.1} 
    & \color{white}{Formalia} 
\end{tabular}}}
\end{snugshade}

\begin{snugshade}
\section*{\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \color{white}{F18-5.1} 
    & \color{white}{Formalia} 
\end{tabular}}
\end{snugshade}

\section*{\begin{snugshade}\begin{tabular}{c|c}
    \color{white}{F18-5.1} 
    & \color{white}{Formalia} 
\end{tabular}\end{snugshade}\vspace{-1cm}}
abc

\section*{\begin{snugshade}\color{white}F18-5.1\quad Formalia\end{snugshade}}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note the `\vspace{-1cm}` in the third variant, for some reason this option takes a lot of vertical space which needs to be corrected a bit.